# How to see Date & time while accessing 17.10 server remotely using xrdp?

Tags: settings, time

I'm using ubuntu server 17.10 and accessing remotely using xrdp. I'm not able to see time and date. How can I resolve this problem

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: What about the `date` command.

Comment: For terminal session you can use `byobu`, it shows time in the right bottom corner.

Comment: @Chai T. Rex -- I'm using windows 10 and remotely accessing through remote desktop connection. I have installed xrdp in ubuntu server .

Comment: @Harsh Sinha -- date command is working , but time is showing wrong. I'm not sure where to edit it.

Comment: @N0rbert -- byobu i'll try.

Comment: @user775134 -- Try using the command `date` with the option `-s`, for details check its man page, but you can do it like `date -s 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`